# Building relationships in Sequelize Javascipt

Tags: javascript, foreign-keys, sequelize.js

I am trying to build a relationship between two tables with sequelize.  However, it is not working as expected.  I want to make a relationship between Company and Customers.

```
Customer.belongsTo(models.Company);
//
// Does not work!
// Customer.belongsTo(models.Company, {
//   foreignKey: {
//     allowNull: false,
//     name: "company_id",
//   },
// });
```

If I was to uncomment out this code neither the "allowNull" or the name change does not work.

[image]

As you can see, 
1) It still creates a column with CompanyId and not "company_id"
2) I am able to write a record with a null value in the field CompanyID

Thoughts?

If I run it with the commented code it creates both "CompanyId" and "company_id"
[image]

Comment: Did you use 'sync' function to create a table?  Show the model definitions.

Comment: It creates both CompanyId and company_id (See my original post with the snippet of the model.)

Comment: You should define company_id as a field of a model with allowNull: true and in the association indicate 

 Customer.belongsTo(models.Company, {
   foreignKey: "company_id"
}